# Calculate business days between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried the following query I got from an earlier question:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, InstallDate, CompleteDate,
  (TRUNC(CompleteDate) - TRUNC(InstallDate) ) +1 - 
  ((((TRUNC(CompleteDate,'D'))-(TRUNC(InstallDate,'D')))/7)*2) -
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(InstallDate,'DY','nls_date_language=english')='SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CompleteDate,'DY','nls_date_language=english')='SAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BusinessDays
FROM Orders
ORDER BY OrderNumber;
```

But I get an 'ORA-01722 - Invalid Number' error.

What am I doing wrong?

Following is my modified code that I'm having issues with:

```
select
CASE WHEN a.reqdt=0 THEN  to_char('01/01/2010') ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-1970','DD-MM-YY') + ( a.reqdt/ 86400000 ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') END AS DT_SENT_TO_VENDOR,
CASE WHEN a.completedt=0 THEN to_char('01/01/2010') ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-1970','DD-MM-YY') + ( a.completedt/ 86400000 ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') END AS COMPLETED_DT,
(CASE WHEN a.completedt=0 THEN to_char('01/01/2010') ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-1970','DD-MM-YY') + ( a.completedt/ 86400000 ), 'dd-mm-yyyyY') END -
CASE WHEN a.reqdt=0 THEN  to_char('01/01/2010') ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-1970','DD-MM-YY') + ( a.reqdt/ 86400000 ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') END ) + 1 -
/*(a.completedt  - a.reqdt ) + 1 -  */
((((TRUNC(a.completedt,'D'))) - (TRUNC(a.reqdt,'D'))/7)*2) -
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(a.reqdt,'DY','nls_date_language=american')='SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -
  (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(a.completedt,'DY','nls_date_language=american')='SAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BusinessDays
  from EST_VER a;
```

Comment: What data types are the table columns? That seems to work if they are DATE types - hopefully you aren't storing dates as strings? (Though this may not get 'business days' - it doesn't know about holidays, so it just counts weekdays)

Comment: The data type for the Dates are stored as Number. Im trying to find the business days between two dates

Comment: Then you need to convert those numbers to dates before you do any manipulation. Oracle can't guess what your numbers represent. Why aren't you using the correct data type?

Comment: I just added the actual code in my initial posting

Comment: Your code sample does not address holidays.  If that is important your approach is fundamentally wrong.  You would benefit from a calendar table that includes that information.  In fact, a calendar table would also make stuff like this easier if holidays were not relevant.

Comment: Thanks .. but currently i have only read access, hence my need to write an sql query to calculate the business days

Comment: The issue we're talking about is the meaning of 'business days', which usually excludes holidays. Your code cannot do that.

Comment: OK, so your 'dates' are epoch offsets. You still need to convert then to actual dates before you do anything with them. `TRUNC(a.completedt,'D')` for example, you need to convert `a.completedt` from a number to a date before you can truncate it.

Comment: Define "business day". What if my company works a 9/80 schedule, or 4 10hr days, or we're in a country that works Sunday through Thursday, or ...?